# Is the unit sphere of a smooth Banach space a smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, banach-spaces

A Banach space X is smooth if at every point of the unit sphere there is only one supporting hyperplane of the unit ball.
Can we say for finite dimensional X, this implies the unit sphere to be differentiable manifold?
The reverse implication is almost tautological.

If not, what is a counterexample to this?

Comment: Could you clarify the term manifold here? Differential geometry isn't specifically my thing, but as I understand it, manifolds are locally homeomorphic to finite-dimensional spaces, which make them locally compact, and the unit sphere of an infinite-dimensional space is not. Perhaps you mean [Banach Manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_manifold)? The linked definition requires the crossover maps be Frechet differentiable, whereas you require the norm to be only Gateaux-smooth, so I anticipate counterexamples there. Could you clarify?

Comment: @ Theo, Sorry, I had in mind finite dimensional Banach space. So I missed it.

Comment: Please, define what you mean by a smooth manifold (specifically, the degree of smoothness). Also, what did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried with [p-norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions)?

Comment: Proposition 3.1 in [these lecture notes](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~izosimov/math534a/Submanifolds.pdf), by Anton Izosimov, shows that this is the case.

Comment: @ Kajelad,  differentiabilty for p-norm prompted me to ask this question. @ Theo how do I know that norm is a differentiable function? is it because the norm is Gateaux differentiable and in finite dimension they agree?

Comment: The question boils down to this: if $f \colon B \to [0,\infty)$ is a convex function on the unit ball $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $f(0)=0$ and for each $\mathbf{a} \neq \mathbf{0}$ there's $x$ such that $f(x) < \mathbf{a} \cdot x$, then $f$ has zero differential at $0$. Still, I don't know the answer.

Comment: @Arun As has been pointed out, this depends somewhat on how you define "smooth manifold" (in particular, do you mean $C^\infty$ or merely $C^k$?), but observe that the unit ball on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the $p$-norm can locally be written as the graph of a function $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\to\mathbb{R}$. These will have varying degrees of smoothness.

Comment: @Arun If you put a space between the @ and the name, you're not tagging the person, so they don't get a notification. You also can't tag two people at once. But yes, the uniqueness of the supporting hyperplane suggests a unique subgradient of the norm, equivalent to (Gateaux) differentiability of the norm at the point (for convex functions in finite dimensions, I believe Gateaux and Frechet are equivalent). Thus, the norm is differentiable everywhere except the origin, and so the norm squared is differentiable everywhere (even at $0$, by special argument).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for in Theorem 4.1. and 4.2 of James's paper
"Orthogonality and linear functionals in normed linear spaces" Tran. AMS, 1947.

He proves that smoothness is equivalent to Gateaux differentiability which is equivalent to the standard differentiability in finite dimension.